# Is there a function to solve data import errors?

Tags: sql-server, data-import

I'm trying to import data from  MS Access to SQL Server, this process used to work, today I'm not able to import the data. When I try to import the data with the SQL Server Import and export wizard shows me the next errors:

```
- Copying to [dbo].[Measurements] (Error)
Messages
Error 0xc0202009: Data Flow Task 1: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005.
An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "Could not allocate a new page for database 'MITSF_2' because of insufficient disk space in filegroup 'PRIMARY'. Create the necessary space by dropping objects in the filegroup, adding additional files to the filegroup, or setting autogrowth on for existing files in the filegroup.".
 (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
 
Error 0xc0209029: Data Flow Task 1: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_INDUCEDTRANSFORMFAILUREONERROR.  The "Destination - Measurements.Inputs[Destination Input]" failed because error code 0xC020907B occurred, and the error row disposition on "Destination - Measurements.Inputs[Destination Input]" specifies failure on error. An error occurred on the specified object of the specified component.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
 (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
 
Error 0xc0047022: Data Flow Task 1: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PROCESSINPUTFAILED.  The ProcessInput method on component "Destination - Measurements" (778) failed with error code 0xC0209029 while processing input "Destination Input" (791). The identified component returned an error from the ProcessInput method. The error is specific to the component, but the error is fatal and will cause the Data Flow task to stop running.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
 (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
 
Error 0xc02020c4: Data Flow Task 1: The attempt to add a row to the Data Flow task buffer failed with error code 0xC0047020.
 (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
 
Error 0xc0047038: Data Flow Task 1: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PRIMEOUTPUTFAILED.  The PrimeOutput method on Source - Measurements returned error code 0xC02020C4.  The component returned a failure code when the pipeline engine called PrimeOutput(). The meaning of the failure code is defined by the component, but the error is fatal and the pipeline stopped executing.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
 (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
```

I tried shrinking the database and truncate the log file, but stills give me the same error.

Comment: *"`Could not allocate a new page for database 'MITSF_2' because of insufficient disk space in filegroup 'PRIMARY'. Create the necessary space by dropping objects in the filegroup, adding additional files to the filegroup, or setting autogrowth on for existing files in the filegroup.`"* There no function to solve that; you need to free up space.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not about programming and you don't need a "function"; you just need to read the error and administer your system accordingly.

Comment: off-topic - belongs on dba as this is really a question about both shrinking the database and about expanding the primary filegroup.

Comment: Yes - this belongs on DBA. Hard disk / shrinking administrative tasks. Unless it can be clarified that his function is a requirement to shrink the database.

Answer (score 0):

Seems pretty clear you're out of disk space:

> Description: "Could not allocate a new page for database 'MITSF_2' because of insufficient disk space in filegroup 'PRIMARY'.

One way this sometimes happens is if you're in FULL recovery mode and not backing up your transaction logs.